# Pass multiple arguments from text "line" to batch command

Tags: batch-file

1.Have a utility to create users user_create.exe:

user_create.bat %1 as-f_name  %2 as-l_name %3 as-id %4 as-email

2. I have a text file with arguments specified on each line and the content will be dynamic, will change every-time.
   input.txt >> f_name, l_name, id and email each are specified on separate lines in the txt.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are there four lines in the text file?

Comment: 1. Are the `as-*` portions part of the command line of `user_create.bat`? 2. Could you please provide a sample text file in your question?

Comment: The command will go like:
user_create.bat %1 %2 %3 %4
And in the input text file values will be like:
f_name
l_name
id
email
each of the values will not be in continuation but rather each will be on new line. Yes, four lines will be in the text file and I want to ready these values from the text. I can create a wrapper to read the text file and pass the argument but the only thing I don't know is how to read each line as an argument value.